# Javascript CreateElement creates empty tables

Tags: javascript, html, html-table, createelement, pre

I'm trying to use a pre html tag to contain some code that I am going to format. I take the code from a pre-existing pre tag, and make a table containing the code, which is then formatted. But every other time I make a td element, with some text in it, an empty table is created instead. My code is as following:

```
function init() {
    var pres = document.getElementsByTagName('pre');

    for (var i = 0; i < pres.length; i++) {
        var elem = pres[i];
        var ourTable = document.createElement('table');

        if (elem.className.toLowerCase() == 'code') {
            var lineCount = 1;
            var linesOfText = elem.innerHTML.split(/\r|\n/);

            for (var j = 0; j < linesOfText.length; j++) { 
                var ourRow = document.createElement('tr');
                var lineNumberTd = document.createElement('td');
                var lineNumberNode = document.createTextNode(lineCount);
                lineNumberTd.appendChild(lineNumberNode);

                ourRow.appendChild(lineNumberTd);

                var code = linesOfText[j];

                var codeTd = document.createElement('td');
                var ourPre = document.createElement('pre');
                ourPre.innerHTML = code;
                codeTd.appendChild(ourPre);
                ourRow.appendChild(codeTd);

                lineCount++;
                ourTable.appendChild(ourRow);
            }
        }

        elem.parentNode.replaceChild(ourTable, elem);
    }
}
window.onload = init;
```

And my HTML is as following:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head runat="server">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="DefaultStyle.css" />
    <title>Autoformatter</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
            <pre class="code">
                        while (!stop)
            {
                while (packetQueue.Count > 0)
                {
                    HandlePacket(packetQueue.Dequeue());
                }
            }
        </pre>
        </div>
    </form>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="PrimaryScript.js" ></script>
</body>
</html>
```

and this generates something like this:

[image: result of the code]

There are empty tables like the one on line 2 in line 4, 6 and 8 aswell.

Comment: Here's a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NYJ4Q/1/) with your code.

Comment: For me it's coming as you expected..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are using a NodeList:

```
var pres = document.getElementsByTagName('pre');

for (var i = 0; i < pres.length; i++) {
```

NodeLists are "live" collections, that is they change. At the beginning you have one pre tag so `pres.length` returns 1. But within the loop you add pre tags. So `pres.length` changes as well. Hence your loop runs again and again.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so I figured out the answer to the problem myself.

Apparently, in some way, the line

```
elem.parentNode.replaceChild(ourTable, elem);
```

got run more times than it should, and therefore it replaced the newly made pre-element with an empty table, since the newly made pre-element did not have the class='code' property set.

Putting that single line INTO the

```
if (elem.className.toLowerCase() == 'code') {
```

and not outside it, fixed my problem.